# As a dual citizen, am I allowed to travel outside of the European Union without using the EU passport?

Tags: schengen, europe, dual-nationality, eu, eu-citizens

My case is the following: I have Brazilian and Italian citizenships and I'm currently living in Germany, for over an year now. I plan to travel to Brazil this holiday, and unfortunately I don't have an Italian passport, only the Brazilian one. What makes it even worse is that the Italian consulate has an appointment ready only in January.

I'm thinking of traveling with my Brazilian passport and my Italian ID, but I'm wondering if that's going to be a problem for the authorities, as I theoretically don't have legal stand to stay in Europe as a Brazilian for a period longer than 3 months (tourism visa for Brazilians), and I'll have to use my Brazilian passport to enter the airplane.

I would like to know how dual citizenship works in this case, if as an Italian without a passport I'm allowed to reenter the European Union. Basically I do have a traveling document, but not a European one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you only had your Brazilian passport, it would bring up some subtle questions about obligations when crossing the border, your rights as EU citizen, what you may or may not do with an expired passport, what the consequences might be in practice, etc. but in that case you don't have to worry about all that. A national ID card is enough, plain and simple.

You can use it to go through the exit border check, to enter the Schengen area, to establish your right to live in the EU and to satisfy German ID obligations (*Ausweispflicht*). I have done all this multiple times with mine and German and EU law actually state as much explicitly. As long as you can prove you are an Italian citizen, there can be no concern about any overstay or lack of stamps in your other passport. There is also no obligation to carry or hold an EU passport for EU citizens (as opposed to holding an official ID document in general, which can be mandatory in some countries and useful to establish your citizenship).

And your Brazilian passport will take care of entering Brazil and satisfying airline checks. In some rare cases (another user experienced that in Sweden), it seems border guards also want to see that you will be able to enter your destination before letting you exit the Schengen area but the Brazilian passport ought to take care of that as well (and I don't think German border guards care at all).

Comment: First-hand experience: When I flew to Turkey and Egypt for vacation, where my German ID card suffices to enter, I did not even have a passport, yet left the Schengen area.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I really appreciate the details! Now I'm much more relaxed ;)

Comment: "I don't think German border guards care at all" - anecdotal evidence aside, I don't think any border guard cares or should care in general. Airlines usually care, but still only because if they let you on a plane and you get denied entry, _they_ have to pay for transporting you back.

Comment: @CompuChip That, and the fines they have to pay if they somehow violated a law in bringing you over anyway.

Comment: @CompuChip Well, they shouldn't but as I said, it seems Swedish border guards do care. Not being a Swedish citizen I don't know either way but there have been Q&A about this on this site.

Comment: `I theoretically don't have legal stand to stay in Europe as a Brazilian` - No, you have the right to live until your last day in EU. A passport is not required at all in the Schengen area. As pointed out in the answer already

Comment: @Alexander I was in Turkey too. I had a passport already but since Turkey and Egypt *have a special agreement* with EU, they would have accepted my local ID even if out of Schengen. Schengen equals no **systematic** border checks, which are enforced in both countries like happened to you

Comment: Apparently if the traveler attempts to return to the EU by way of Italy, there could be a problem.  See [Is it against the EU freedom of movement for Italy refuse entry to an EU citizen with only an ID card flying from outside the EU/EFTA?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/24017/333) on [Law.SE].

Comment: @phoog After I fell victim to this (by being refused boarding on a flight Istanbul-Bergamo, which is also when I learnt of this) I mailed my IATA contact and it turns out their Italian government sources screwed up big time. That quirk has been taken off Timatic

Comment: @Coke it seems like there might be an interesting story behind that.  Do you know anything more?

Comment: @phoog Sadly not: although I've spoken to IATA for almost 3 years (with the sourcing manager being my dedicated contact) I get the impression that they wouldn't want to reveal who their sources in each country are, something I would really like to know for Dominica, Jordan and Tunisia as there's a matter in each where I'm 95% sure they've screwed up. After this, obviously, I'd like to know about Italy too: as well as e-Mailing my IATA contact, I also e-mailed the Italian MFA and MOI, none of which have replied to me. Only my IATA contact let me know that the mistake's been corrected

Comment: Bottom line @GabrielChecchiaVitali, you'll be absolutely fine. In Europe, only show your Italian ID card

Comment: @Relaxed Perhaps you're talking about the Swedish regulation that Swedish ID cards aren't accepted for exiting Sweden directly for a country outside both EU and Schengen, even if accepting it for entry (such as Serbia)